# The “Color Category” icon disappears when you enable “Show as Conversations”

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When you set “Color Categories” to mail, you can see color icons on the “CATEGORIES” column in the message list (like screenshots [shown on this site](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/category-color-display-inbox/)).

> [image]

But when you enable “Show as Conversations,” the color icons disappear from the message list. You can see the “CATEGORIES” column, but it only shows the name of the categories.

Is there any way to show the “Color Category” icon on the message list when you enable “Show as Conversations?”

Answer (score 1):

According to my tests, whether or not to enable "Shown as Conversations" does not affect the color display of categories. As shown in the following figure, the colors can be displayed normally:

**Not enable "Shown as Conversations":**
[image]

**Enable "Shown as Conversations":**
[image]

In order to better solve your issue, please provide more information about your issue:

1. What's the version of your Outlook (File>Office Account>About Outlook)? Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.
2. Does this issue occur in a specific folder or all folders?

In addition, it's suggested that you could try the following steps to troubleshooting:

1. Please go to View tab>Current group>click on **Reset View**. And then enable "Shown as Conversations" again to check if there're any differences.

   [image]
2. If it doesn't work, please try a command to **reset the view settings**: win+R> type: **outlook /cleanviews**.(This command will delete all custom view settings. If you need to keep other view settings, please remember to back up.)
3. If the issue still exists, considering that it may be caused by the damage of the profile in the outlook client, it is suggested that you could try to **create a new profile**(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.
4. If the above doesn't work, considering that it would also be affected when the outlook program itself is damaged. It is recommended that you try to **[fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something weird going on with the situation the OP is asking about because I have noticed this problem too. I think it is a bug that Microsoft needs to fix. Like the OP, I prefer to have the reading pane on the bottom with Conversation view turned on. The issue seems to have something to do with the format of other columns.

For example, if the Categories column is between the Size column and the Mention column (as shown in the previous reply from Christy), then everything works as expected. But if the Categories column is moved to the left to be between the Attachment column and the From column, then the colored rectangle disappears and only the category name is visible in the Categories column.

I want the Categories column to be one of the columns on the left side of the screen (grouped with Importance, Icon, and Attachment) because I use it like an icon. I reduce the width of the Categories column to be small enough that I see only the colored rectangle (and not the category name that follows in the rest of the column). In this way, I use the Categories column as a visual cue. For example, I have rules that assign the red category to messages sent only to me and the blue category to messages sent from my boss.

Here is the fix / workaround that I discovered: I created a new column of type text. The name of this column is not important; I called mine "." and I moved this new user-created column to the top of the list so it appears in the left-most position on the screen. I made the width of this column as small as Outlook would allow me. Then I put the Categories column as the 2nd column in the list between "." and Importance.

When the new column exists on the far left-edge of the screen, the Categories column displays the colored rectangle as expected. But if I swap the order of these two columns (Categories first and "." second), then the Categories column no longer displays the colored rectangles. Putting a very thin column of type text immediately to the left of the Categories column seems to be one workaround for this problem.